# Why is this openGL code not outputing anything?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl

Following is a cpp code for drawing `LorenzAttractor` using `SubWindows`. Pls let me know why the code isn't showing any primitives.. surprised why even the coordinate axis does not show up..

1. Main.cpp http://pastebin.com/bGqcBzfJ
2. OpenGLFramework.h http://pastebin.com/8L3gk5uD
3. MyFramework.h http://pastebin.com/CZfskfVF
4. LorenzAttractor.h http://pastebin.com/t6GN1khg

Kindly bear with me for coding the functions in .h files.

EDIT: OpenGLFramework is a baseclass and is being extended by the MyFramework class. I set params and then call the `startFramework()` to start rendering the figures on screen.

I checked each and every OpenGL function I used, but could not figure out why the output is a blanck screen. Pls suggest and also any tools for debugging the OpenGL programs? Debugging is a headache thing in graphics :(.

Code snippets:

```
void startFramework(int argc, char *argv[]) {

                    setInstance();

                    // Initialize GLUT
                    glutInit(&argc, argv);
                    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
                    glutInitWindowPosition(WINDOW_X_POSITION, WINDOW_Y_POSITION);
                    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);

                    mainWindow = glutCreateWindow(instance->title.c_str());
                    glutSetWindow(mainWindow);

                    // callbacks for main window
                    glutDisplayFunc(renderMainWindow);
                    glutReshapeFunc(changeSizeWrapper);
                    glutIdleFunc(renderSceneAllWrapper);

                    //subwindows
                    int subwindowWidth = (width - numberOfSubWindows * border) / numberOfSubWindows;
                    int subWindowHeight = height - border;

                    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfSubWindows; i++) {
                            subWindow[i] = glutCreateSubWindow(mainWindow, (i * width / numberOfSubWindows) + (border / 2), border / 2, subwindowWidth, subWindowHeight);
                            glutSetWindow(subWindow[i]);
                            glutDisplayFunc(renderWrapper);

                            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
                            glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

                            // register callbacks
                            //glutIgnoreKeyRepeat(1);
                            glutKeyboardFunc(processNormalKeysWrapper);
                            glutSpecialFunc(pressKeyWrapper);
                            glutSpecialUpFunc(releaseKeyWrapper);
                            glutMouseFunc(mouseButtonWrapper);
                    }      

                    glutMainLoop();
            }
```

`renderWrapper()` would call the `draw()`..

```
void draw() {
                        if( 1 == getNumberOfSubWindows() ) {
                                        setWindowContext(0);

                                        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                                        glLoadIdentity();
                                        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

                                        invokeGlutLookAt();

                                        draw3DCoordinateAxis();

                                        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numLorenzAttractors; i++) {
                                                lorenzAttractor[i].simulate();
                                        }

                                        glutSwapBuffers();
                        } else if( getNumberOfSubWindows() == numLorenzAttractors ) {
                                for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numLorenzAttractors; i++) {
                                        setWindowContext(i);

                                        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                                        glLoadIdentity();
                                        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

                                        invokeGlutLookAt();

                                        draw3DCoordinateAxis();
                                        lorenzAttractor[i].simulate();

                                        glutSwapBuffers();
                                }
                        }
                }
```

Comment: Reduce the problem to a version that you can paste into the question. You're code has a ton of irrelevant stuff, like keyboard handling. You might even find the bug yourself in the process.

Comment: @MarceloCantos Done.. I pasted the important functions above.. sorry for the previous post.. need some proper sleep :|..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you set the Matrices in draw(), glLoadIdentity() should go after glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW), at least if you want to set the model view matrix, and I see no pojection matrix. By default OpenGl draws the only stuff in the [0,1] range of all 3 dimensions, and you use the projection matriy to transform it to the angle and size you want, so if you don't set the projection matrix you won't see anything.

Anyways, I don't even understand what your code does...

Comment: Thanks for the inputs EvanDark.. The code is part of the framework I came up with so it wont be straight forward! The intension is to put all handlers in the base class while the specific derived class has the `virtual draw()` functionality implemented..

Comment: Got the simulation working.. `invokeGlutLookAt()` was the culprit.. I was assigning wrong variables and thus the behavior..